# Openjpa lock does not work

Tags: java, sql, locking, openjpa

In a project with OpenJPA 2.1 and oracle database I use mixed lock mode, which default has optimistic locking but can use pessimistic as well. But it does not work for me as I expected.
So I wrote small test for openjpa locking.

Persistance.xml config:

```
<properties>

    <property name="openjpa.Optimistic" value="false" />
    <property name="openjpa.LockManager" value="mixed" /> 
<!--    <property name="openjpa.LockManager"value="mixed(VersionCheckOnReadLock=true,VersionUpdateOnWriteLock=true)" /> -->
    <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported" />
    <property name="openjpa.slice.ConnectionDriverName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="openjpa.slice.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:******" />
    <property name="openjpa.slice.ConnectionUserName" value="user" />
    <property name="openjpa.slice.ConnectionPassword" value="userpassword" />
    <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="validate" />
    <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" value="native(ForeignKeys=true)" />
    <property name="openjpa.Log"
        value="DefaultLevel=INFO, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE" />
</properties>
```

My simple test code:

```
Configuration config = entityManager.find(Configuration.class, 10025984L);
entityManager.lock(config, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

In sql trace is see, that after lock method calling OpenJPA does not execute any additional query to database. Single sql query:

```
TRACE  [Thread-7] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 874198043, conn 1773300146> executing prepstmnt 1809148885 SELECT t0.VERSION FROM Configuration t0 WHERE t0.ID = ? [params=?]
```

What I do wrong and how can I get lock for one entity instance?

Answer (score 2):

I found soulution. The reason was in JPA settings. I just remove property:

```
<property name="openjpa.Optimistic" value="false" />
```

And everything became work fine.